# How to refresh data with Automation Services when the source is an Excel file?

Tags: spotfire

If it is impossible, then perhaps some good idea for a workaround ?
Using db as a source is not an option.
So far the files must be saved into Library manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the same excel file (not changing the name, etc), you can save it to a network share and make sure the scheduled updates user and / or service account for your server has read access to this directory, then use automation services to schedule your updates how ever frequent you want.

Comment: there's also a flag you have to set in the `web.config` file. I don't have it offhand but check the webplayer manual.

Comment: @scsimon - did you test it yourself ? and if so, on which version was it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the UNC path for the file on the shared network drive where the service accounts have access in order for Automation Services to be able to access it.